# iPhone send mail application

Tags: iphone

I am trying to build an iPhone application which can send emails wile running.
Until now I found the mailto:// url format, but this quits the application.
MFMailComposeViewController allows me to return to the application, but its interface seems to be fixed.Does anybody know if it is possible to modify it? (aspect and adding some more commands, not just Cancel and Send, or adding another button which could also send the message).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to customize MFMailComposeViewController's view. Even if you would somehow hack it Apple could reject the app on that term.

Comment: I was afraid of this, but it was worth trying. Thank you.